# Single Sign On Solution

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to come up with a single sign on solution for a small team. I've got four applications:

- dokuwiki
- redmine
- svn
- owncloud

All of these I was told by folks support LDAP, and that it was the best way to go to get a single sign on between all of them. I especially liked the idea for SVN since otherwise I'd have to manually edit a file to set up new users in there.

I've first tried doing things with phpldapadmin, I was supposedly able to edit stuff in the ldap server but all my attempts at logging into dokuwiki never succeeded. I also tried LAM, however that just never functioned at all. Could never make any changes to the server.

One thing I noticed turned out differently than in some tutorials was that ldapsearch didn't return any specifics:

```
vbox@testbox ~ $ ldapsearch -x
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
    search: 2
    result: 32 No such object

    # numResponses: 1
```

But phpldapadmin didn't complain so I just kept going. I set things up with dc=localhost, then made an organizational unit ou=groups and ou=users. Then I made a posixgroup with GID 500 called test, and a user called tester as a generic user.

I then following some more instructions set dokuwiki to look at localhost for the server with the default port 389. I set it to look at

```
ou=users,dc=localhost
```

for user accounts, and

```
ou=groups,dc=localhost
```

for the groups. I used the default group and user filters, set the system to use version 3 of ldap, and that was all I supposedly had to do to make it run on anonymous bind. I did try putting in the admin account for the bind user as well but that didn't work either.

At this point I'm out of ideas for things to try.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be wrong, or know of any other simpler methods I could use to implement SSO between these four services?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an expert at LDAP myself, but `dc=localhost` doesn't sound like a good idea to me. Use a domain instead and if you don't have one, make one up. I've spent a couple of weeks now trying to get my head around LDAP, but it seems to have quite a learning curve. In terms of administering the server, I found [Apache Directory Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) to be really helpful if you don't know what you're doing (as is the case with myself).

Comment: The reason I have that set to localhost is because I was trying to create a proof-of-concept service to see if I could even make it run.

ADS looks pretty handy, I'll have to investigate it further. For now I think I'm going to put the quest for SSO aside and focus on actually getting work done. Multiple sign on is clunky but functional...

Thanks!